# how to start mongoose without sudo in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongoose, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

my mongodb is running  with command
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
in ubuntu 20.04

I want to run mongod without sudo command i.e. `systemctl start mongod`
when i am running `systemctl start mongod` then it prompt for authentication password which is more hell than using sudo command

is there anyway to do so , So that i can get rid of sudo and the password.

Comment: What is your problem to use `sudo`? You can switch to root user.

Comment: Because of the level of impact that `systemctl` can have on the system, it’s generally reserved for privileged users, such s system administrators. I guess it would be possible to run `systemctl` as non-privileged user but this would introduce serious security flaws to your system.

Comment: i made a logic that

Comment: I made a logic that when I run npm run dev , its also start mongod (i m using child process of nodejs) to do so.

Comment: Then maybe start it directly with `/usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` instead of `systemctl start mongod` Ensure your current user gas privileges to write all needed files.